# How to use the 'privacy' attribute function in Laravel Rebing GraphQL?

Tags: laravel, graphql

i'm working on a graphql API using [Laravel GraphQL](https://github.com/rebing/graphql-laravel#privacy).

As shown in the documentation "Privacy" section, it should be possible to add callback function to a GraphQLType fields privacy attribute. The field is supposed to return null, when the callback returns false.

Similar to the example in the laravel graphql Docs, i've added a privacy callback like so:

```
public function fields(): array {
    return [
        'email'               => [
            'type'        => Type::string(),
            'description' => 'The email of user',
            'privacy'     => function(User $user): bool {
                return $user->isMe();
            }
        ],
    ];
}
```

It appears to me, that this callback function never gets called.
I [read something](https://github.com/rebing/graphql-laravel/issues/459) about a possible requirement, that i should resolve my query using the $getSelectFields function to query the $fields manually $with the selected columns. But unfortunately the $select

```
 public function resolve($root, $args, $context, ResolveInfo $info, Closure $getSelectFields) {
    $fields = $getSelectFields();
    $with = $fields->getRelations(); // empty array
    $select = $fields->getSelect(); // empty array

    return User::select($select)->with($with)->get();
}
```

In my case this does not make any difference.

In my query resolver i do as following:

```
public function resolve($root, $args, $context, ResolveInfo $info, Closure $getSelectFields) {

    /** @var SelectFields $fields */
    $fields = $getSelectFields();
    $select = $fields->getSelect();
    $with = $fields->getRelations();

    exit(var_dump($fields)); // #RESULT
}
```

My result looks like this:

```
object(Rebing\\GraphQL\\Support\\SelectFields)#4668 (2) { 
    [\"select\":\"Rebing\\GraphQL\\Support\\SelectFields\":private]=>  array(0) {}  
    [\"relations\":\"Rebing\\GraphQL\\Support\\SelectFields\":private]=>  array(0) {} 
}
```

**So my question is: "How do i use the privacy attribute callback in Laravel Rebing GraphQL?"**

I'm using:

- PHP 7.3
- Laravel 7.17
- Rebing Graphql Laravel 5.1

Thanks in advance,

greets Jules

Comment: Is there anyone who could help me with this issue? 
Any kind of custom workaround to solve this purpose would be highly time consuming.. :/

Answer (score 0):

Some more Details about my use case
**EpUser.php**

```php
namespace App\GraphQL\Type;

use App\CommunityImage;
use App\User;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use GraphQL\Type\Definition\Type;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Rebing\GraphQL\Support\Facades\GraphQL;
use Rebing\GraphQL\Support\Type as GraphQLType;

class EpUser extends GraphQLType {
    protected $attributes = [
        'name'        => 'EpUser',
        'description' => 'A type',
        'model'       => User::class,                                                 
    ];

    public function fields(): array {
        return [
            'id'                  => [
                'type'        => Type::nonNull(Type::int()),
                'description' => 'The id of the user',
                'privacy'     => function(User $user): bool {
                    return false;
                }
            ],
            'email'               => [
                'type'        => Type::string(),
                'description' => 'The email of user',
                'privacy'     => function(User $user): bool {
                    return $user->isMe();                                                
                }
            ],
            'firstName'           => [
                'type'        => Type::string(),
                'description' => 'The firstName of user'
            ],
            'lastName'            => [
                'type'        => Type::string(),
                'description' => 'The lastName of user'
            ],
            'fullName'            => [
                'type'        => Type::string(),
                'description' => 'The fullName of user',
                'selectable'  => false,
                'resolve'     => function(User $user) {
                    return $user->firstName . " " . $user->lastName;
                }
            ],
            'gender'              => [
                'type'        => Type::string(),
                'description' => 'The gender of the user'
            ],
            'isOnline'            => [
                'type'        => Type::boolean(),
                'description' => '',
                'selectable'  => false,
                'resolve'     => function(User $user, $args) {
                    return $user->isOnline();
                }
            ]
        ];
    }

    [...]
```

And this is the UsersQuery which should respond with a user pagination object, that contains an array of users with a privacy attribute:

**UsersQuery.php**

```php
namespace App\GraphQL\Query;

use App\Artist;
use App\FilePath;
use Closure;
use GraphQL\Type\Definition\Type;
use Rebing\GraphQL\Support\Query;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use GraphQL\Type\Definition\ResolveInfo;
use Rebing\GraphQL\Support\Facades\GraphQL;

use App\User;

class UsersQuery extends Query {
    protected $attributes = [
        'name'        => 'UsersQuery',
        'description' => 'A query',
        'model'       => User::class,
    ];

    public function type(): Type {
        return GraphQL::type('userPagination');
    }

    public function authorize($root, array $args, $ctx, ResolveInfo $resolveInfo = NULL, $getSelectFields = NULL): bool {
        return Auth::check();
    }

    public function args(): array {
        return [
            'id'         => [
                'type'        => Type::int(),
                'description' => 'The id of the user'
            ],
            'slug'       => [
                'type'        => Type::string(),
                'description' => 'The slug of the user'
            ],
            'pagination' => [
                'type'        => Type::nonNull(GraphQL::type('paginationInput')),
                'description' => 'The pagination of the users to query',
                'rules'       => 'required',
            ],
            'search'     => [
                'type'        => Type::string(),
                'description' => 'a string to search for users'
            ],
            'roles'      => [
                'type'        => Type::listOf(Type::string()),
                'description' => 'The roles of the user',
                'rules'       => 'sometimes|required|array|in:user,developer,administrator'
            ]
        ];
    }

    public function resolve($root, $args, $context, ResolveInfo $info, Closure $getSelectFields) {
        if(isset($args['id']) || isset($args['slug'])) {
            if(isset($args['slug'])) {
                $user = User::where('slug', $args['slug'])->first();
            } else {
                $user = User::find($args['id']);
            }
            return [
                'items'     => $args['pagination']['limit'] > 0 && $user ? [$user] : NULL,
                'itemTotal' => $user ? 1 : 0
            ];
        }

        $sortBy = $args['pagination']['sortBy'] ?? 'id';
        $sortByDesc = isset($args['pagination']['sortByDesc']) ? $args['pagination']['sortByDesc'] : true;
        $sortByType = $sortByDesc ? 'desc' : 'asc';

        $search = false;

        if(isset($args['search']) && $args['search']) {
            $search = true;
            $query = User::search($args['search']);
        } else {
            $query = User::query();
        }

        if(!empty($sortBy)) {
            $query->orderBy($sortBy, $sortByType);
        }

        // Todo: eloquent search can't serach for whereHas
        if(isset($args['roles']) && !$search) {
            if(is_array($args['roles'])) {
                foreach($args['roles'] as &$role) {
                    $query->whereHas('roles',
                        function($q) use ($role) {
                            $q->where('name', $role);
                        });
                }
            } else {
                $query->whereHas('roles',
                    function($q) use ($args) {
                        $q->where('name', $args['roles']);
                    });
            }
        }

        if($search) {
            $userPaginationObject = [
                'itemTotal' => $query->count(),
                'items'     => $query->getWithLimitAndOffset($args['pagination']['limit'],
                    $args['pagination']['offset'])
            ];
        } else {
            $userPaginationObject = [
                'itemTotal' => $query->count(),
                'items'     => $query->limit($args['pagination']['limit'])->offset($args['pagination']['offset'])->get()
            ];
        }

        return $userPaginationObject;
    }
}
```